# Null Pointer Exception Kotlin app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When running the code it shows me this error,

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.github.bassaer.chatmessageview.view.ChatView.setOnClickSendButtonListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.joshua.app.ChatView.onCreate(ChatView.kt:62)
```

This is my code 
The first line is where the error shows...

```
   my_chat_view.setOnClickSendButtonListener(listener = View.OnClickListener {
            my_chat_view.send(Message.Builder()
                    .setUser(human)
                    .setRight(true)
                    .setText(my_chat_view.inputText)
                    .build()
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_chat_view` is a null, so it's not initialized (that's what the error is saying - you are calling `setOnClickSendButtonListener` on a null). You should have probably provided more code to get help with this.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the  `my_chat_view` initialization